# Detect websites url requested from browsers using .Net?

Tags: .net, http, url, proxy, network-programming

I'm writing Windows Service and I want it to log every website url the user requested from any browser. I'm using pcap.net which captures every http packet, but I can't map packets to websites correctly. I couldn't find anything useful while googling. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you managed to get HTTP packet payload, extracting first line which contains http verb + resource location, and HTTP header HOST would give the full url. For this page it looks like:

```
GET /questions/9173570/detect-websites-url-requested-from-browsers-using-net HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tomek. I do exactly what you wrote to extract url from packet, but the problem is somewhere else (probably my question wasn't clear).  Requesting this page from browser results with the http packet similar to the one you wrote, as well as many other packets (for example GET http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=... HTTP/1.1). How to associate these "other" packets with the requested website, so as I know that they are results of requesting www.stackoverflow.com/questions/... ? I want to ignore them and just log www.stackoverflow.com/questions/...

Comment: Check another HTTP header: `Referer`, in the initial request there is no referer header. Watch for favicon.ico, I noticed the request for it doesn't have referer heder ether. I guess you would have to play a bit with Fiddler to check other "corner cases".